# Build out a WordPress MultiSite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I’m trying to build a WordPress multisite.

I want clients to be able to fill out information for a template site, upload pictures, videos and possibly files.

Is this something that can be done using WordPress? I considered using a page builder like Beaver Builder but I don’t think it will work. At least that’s what they told me.

I also wanted to have it where clients can choose their own urls such as www.example.com/choose-your-url.

What’s the best way to go about this?

Comment: Yes, all you mentioned can be done using wordpress or wordpress multisite. It's just depending on what you're trying to acieve and what access you want to provide to clients. Use wp roles: [wp roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Network in your wordpress setup.
 1. Allow Multisite in your config.php file. Add this code:
    define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

2. Install Network under Administration > Tools > Network Setup
3. Add your site under My site menu on top right.

   For more info go to https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score -1):

I am a big fan of WordPress multisite. Please Follow this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpFGRCj2R9g

Comment: Please add more specific detail to your answer, which part of the video outlines the solution to the question? This is a link to a tutorial with a lot of irrelevant information. Anyone can post a link to a tutorial, answers on SO must be specific to a question.